# Trying to calculate the average score for a rating system

Tags: excel

I am trying to calculate an average score. I have a rating system set up from 1-5 and they are divided by colors.
I have a few columns that are days in one month and for some ratings/colors I have some random data which acts as votes for each rating.
Is there a way to calculate the average score?

The data is set like this:

```
Score   07/01/2019  08/01/2019  09/01/2019  
1        1           0           2  
2        0           0           1  
3        1           0           0  
4        0           0           0  
5        0           0           0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment above you want the **average score per day.**  So you need to multiple the score (column A) against the number of votes for that score (column B, C, D depending on date.

If your table above goes from A1:D6, then **put this in B7**

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$6,B2:B6)/SUM(B2:B6)
```

This gives you an average of 2 for 7/1 Because (1*1 +3*1)/2 =2.

You can copy the formula across to C7, D7 etc.

You will get a "DIV/0" error if you have no votes. This can be made more pretty as follows:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$6,B2:B6)/SUM(B2:B6),"No votes")
```

All this does is say "No Votes" instead of returning an error. You could change the text to anything, or leave it "" for a blank cell if you want.

If you wanted the score for the whole lot, you can use this (e.g. put it in A10 or wherever using an *array formula*.  You will need to enter the forumale then press **ctrl-shift-enter** otherwise it will not work.

```
=SUM(A2:A6*B2:D6)/SUM(B2:D6)
```

if it works, you should get the answer 1.6 and you will see { } in the formula bar after you press ctrl-shift-enter.

PS I don't think that the accepted answer will give you average score. It will give you average number of votes.  You can test this by putting all the votes in row 6 and seeing that the average score won't increase.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to calculate an average for all, ignoring the 0 entries, which presumably are not scores given your 1-5 scoring methodology. If so, try this (assuming "Score" is in cell A1):

```
=SUM(B2:D6)/COUNT(B2:D6)
```

Comment: Thats a nice way to do it. But what if i want to calculate the average score per day?